# How to catch the EVT_HEADER_BEGIN_RESIZE event from wx.HeaderCtrl when working with the wx.grid.Grid table

Tags: events, grid, wxpython

I need to limit column stretch when

> EVT_HEADER_BEGIN_RESIZE: The user started to drag the separator to the right of the column with the specified index

I was able to catch the sizes after stretching the column using wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CMD_COL_SIZE, but I caught the dynamic change only through the EVT_MOTION mouse event. This attempt produces no errors, but it doesn't work either.

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(12, 8)
        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_HEADER_BEGIN_RESIZE, self.OnColSize)

        #self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_CMD_COL_SIZE, self.OnColSize)

    def OnColSize(self, event):
        print(event.GetPosition())
        event.Skip()


class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Test Grid", size=(1000, 500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        myGrid = MyGrid(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, -1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

How to catch, dynamically changed by the user, the width of a table column?

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which Operating system you are using but the following seems to work on Linux, using wxPython '4.2.1 gtk3 (phoenix) wxWidgets 3.2.2.1'

**Edit:**

Regards the reporting of a column or row size change being reported in real-time, that would involve an event for each pixel of difference, so I can see why they didn't include it as an event.

Pragmatically, your best bet is probably to reset the size to the maximum, if that is exceeded. I've just printed it out but you could output a messagebox or just resize it and say nothing.

```
import wx
import wx.grid


class MyGrid(wx.grid.Grid):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent)
        self.CreateGrid(12, 8)
        self.parent = parent

        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_COL_SIZE, self.OnColSize)
        self.Bind(wx.grid.EVT_GRID_ROW_SIZE, self.OnRowSize)

    def OnColSize(self, event):
        col = event.GetRowOrCol()
        sz = self.GetColSize(col)
        if sz > 200:
            self.SetColSize(col, 200)
            print("Column", col, "width limited to 200")
        event.Skip()

    def OnRowSize(self, event):
        row = event.GetRowOrCol()
        print("Row resized", event.GetRowOrCol())
        print(self.GetRowSize(row))
        event.Skip()

class MyForm(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self):

        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Test Grid", size=(1000, 500))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        myGrid = MyGrid(panel)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(myGrid, -1, wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(sizer)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyForm().Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I have windows 10 and your code shows only after the action is completed, but I need it DURING the column stretching.

Comment: Yes, I also came to a similar answer, but I don't like it, because it can annoy the user with the "springiness" of the table. I would like the stretch to go to the border of the window, and not to the border of the monitor.